# vim: why col() return byte, but not column

Tags: unicode, vim

While editing Unicode text, I realized that Vim function `col('.')` returns current byte postion on the line, not character or column. So this code didn't work properly:

```
let cur_column = col('.')
...
execute "normal! " . cur_column . '|'
```

It moves the cursor on wrong forward postion everytime I'm on non-ASCII line.

I'm using [airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) plugin, which shows me a cursor position in statusline, and it uses byte position too, not character. But on vim without any plugins it shows me line,byte-character, so pressumably it's possible to get the right information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use another function:

```
virtcol('.')
```

which is the screen column of cursor.